# iis facturascript routing bootstrap css

Tags: iis, routes

i have try to install facturascripts in a windows server, server it´s working fine with many websites in php with laravel, wordpress, .... but when i try to put facturascripts in a domain it doesn´t work, i have translate .htaccess to a web.config file, but still not working.

i think the problem is with routing system, so i execute composer install and npm install to be sure everything is ok, but still nothing. bootstrap css and js files gives error 404, but the route chrome gives me is correct.

someone has facturascript 2020 working in IIS??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you're a new contributor, so I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please enable failed request tracing and post more details error inside the log file. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing

Answer (score 0):

Check that the NPM dependencies have actually been downloaded in the `node_modules` folder. I recently saw a case that `npm install` failed on a Windows machine.

Here is the FacturaScripts [official website](https://facturascripts.com) with documentation to answer these questions.